# SONY Gold 7.1 Headset won't work after trying to upload sound

Tags: ps4, gaming-accessories

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

**I had to reset the headphones and pair them up with the USB bluetooth stick again. This is a very easy and quick process to do. Still I do not know if uploading sound modes for various games will work out in the end. The instructions on how to reset the headphones can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkNeR-yBfpQ)**

I recently got the Sony Gold 7.1 headset and it used to work perfectly. I downloaded the Headset Companion App and tried to upload Far Cry 4 sound mode. After that the Headset would not make any sound (it would not output sound). I tried to reset it to the factory modes through the Headset Companion App and nothing. It won't work nor with PS4 or my computer wirelessly.

What can I possibly do?

By the way, the headphones work with cable so the problem is obviously in the wireless connection.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the Sony Gold headset. Do NONE of the sound options work, or just slot 2 (the customized slot)?

Comment: Yes, indeed the Sony Gold Headset. None of them work. Please help!

Comment: Does it show the headset as connected (on your tv) if you switch it on? If you adjust the volume levels, do those show on screen as well? Have you checked the sound and accessory settings on the PS4?

Comment: Yes, PS4 sees the headphones, it says they are the output, it shows the battery level etc and I have checked it actually works as input. For some reason it won't give any output.

Comment: Have you tried changing the chat volume? I doesn't say anywhere (that I know of) but it's actually tied to overall volume. So if you actually brought that level down to 0, you might not hear anything.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it should still be working on your PC regardless... If your PS4 output is fine (which it should be) and you didn't change any accessory settings and it **only** stopped working after you tried to upload the sound mode (and didn't do anything else), I would honestly just return it for a new one... There is no reason that function should have disabled your sound.

Comment: It is exactly as you said. I have not done anything else other than first try to upload the Far Cry 4 sound mode and then try to reset it since it would not work.

Comment: @DangerZone do you think it might have to do something with the fact that PS network is undergoing maintenance right now?

Comment: I would be **EXTREMELY** surprised if that was the cause. Try reinstalling the companion app and then uploading a non-FC4 sound profile when you get a chance. You could also test it offline if the network being down spooks you.

Comment: @DangerZone I cannot reinstall it, PS network is down! I will try tomorrow and see what happens. Maybe I can ask the store to replace them..

Comment: @DangerZone I had to be redirected to SONY service. Since they headphones have a guarantee the problem will be fixed but I assume it will take a good 2-3 weeks if not more. Very annoying. By the way, when I turn the headphones on the light becomes pink in the beginning! I do not know what this actually means.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting and in devices select audio devices and turn your sound from the headset to all audio instead of just chat audio